Why does it say the whole generation died, if Yocheved was still alive?
Shmot 1:6 says

וַיָּ֤מׇת יוֹסֵף֙ וְכׇל־אֶחָ֔יו וְכֹ֖ל הַדּ֥וֹר הַהֽוּא
And Yosef and all his brothers and the whole generation died.

Yocheved was part of the 70 people who went down to Egypt, and those 70 people are that generation (מיתת כל הדור פי' כל הע' נפש).
My question is: If Yocheved was still alive, why does it say the whole generation died?

She was a daughter of Levi,  not a sister. The generation - brothers of Yosef.

@Y DJ "...and those 70 people are that generation (מיתת כל הדור פי' כל הע' נפש)."

Midrash Lekach Tov explains that the phrase "all that generation" is a generalization that shouldn't be taken literally:

בני שמעון למשפחותם.  רבי (ישמעאל) אומר (בראשית מו) שאול בן הכנענית הוא
זמרי בן סלוא שהכליא עונות משפחתו. ומה שמו שלומיאל בן צורישדי. שהיה
במפקד במדבר סיני. ואל תתמה שהרי שאול בן הכנענית היה מיורדי מצרים והיה
עד סוף ארבעים שנה של מדבר. והא כתיב (שמות א׳:ו׳-ז׳) וימת יוסף וכל אחיו
וכל הדור ההוא. תשובתך שהרי סרח בת אשר היתה מיורדי מצרים וחיית והיא
נחשבת בערבות יריחו. ואין למדין מן הכללות ואפילו במקום שנאמר בו חוץ:
The descendants of Simeon according to their families: Rabbi
(Yishmael) says (Bereshit 46) that Shaul, the son of the
Canaanite woman, is Zimri, son of Salu, who tarnished the reputation
of his family through their sins. His other name is Shlumiel, son of
Tzurishaddai, who was listed in the census in the wilderness of Sinai.
And do not be surprised, for Shaul, the son of the Canaanite woman,
was one of those who went down to Egypt and lived until the end of the
forty years in the wilderness. But doesn’t it say (Shemot 1:6-7) "And
Joseph died, and all his brothers, and all that generation"?
Your answer is that Serach, the daughter of Asher, was one of those
who went down to Egypt, and she lived and was still present in the
plains of Jericho. And we don't derive from generalizations, even in places where exceptions are stated.


Chetzron was also alive according to the midrash that he was Yefuneh (we know Kalev's age from a pasuk in Yehoshua)

@Heshy I think the medrash is lav davka
